# CEPH RGW doesn't respond well with AWS SDK C++ S3 CreateBucketOutcome

Tags: amazon-s3, ceph, aws-sdk-cpp

I am trying to use AWS SDK C++ S3 on Ceph Rados Object Gateway, called RGW.

## My Environment

- Ceph 17.2.6 (Quincy)
- g++ (GCC) 11.2.1 20220127 (Red Hat 11.2.1-9)
- AWS SDK C++ S3 latest version (Maybe.. 1.11.209 ??)
- CentOS 8 Stream

## Problem

`CreateBucket` works. But `CreateBucketOutcome` doesn't work. Threrfore, I can't be aware even it creates bucket well or not.
`Aws::S3::Model::CreateBucketOutcome::IsSuccess()` doesn't work properly.
It always response the error, `Xml Parse Error`.

- `Aws::S3::Model::CreateBucketOutcome::GetError().GetExceptionName()`: Xml Parse Error
- `Aws::S3::Model::CreateBucketOutcome::GetError().GetMessage()`: XML_ERROR_PARSING_TEXT

The problem is that, I can't get raw xml message because the function is `protected`.

## Code

I wrote the example code, for creating 2 buckets, listing buckets, deleting 1 bucket, and listing buckets in serial order.

`Aws::S3::S3Client::CreateBucket` is work as you can see on bucket list. However, `Aws::S3::Model::CreateBucketOutcome` doesn't work properly.
(Of course, `DeleteBucket` is working properly without any trouble.)

### Create Bucket

```cpp
void CreateBucket(std::string bucketName) {
    Aws::Client::ClientConfiguration clientConfig;
    clientConfig.endpointOverride = "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:PORT";
    clientConfig.scheme = Aws::Http::Scheme::HTTP;
    clientConfig.verifySSL = false;

    Aws::Auth::AWSCredentials credentials;
    credentials.SetAWSAccessKeyId("____________________");
    credentials.SetAWSSecretKey("________________________________________");

    Aws::S3::S3Client client = Aws::S3::S3Client(credentials, clientConfig, Aws::Client::AWSAuthV4Signer::PayloadSigningPolicy::Never, false);
    Aws::S3::Model::CreateBucketRequest request;
    request.SetBucket(bucketName);
    Aws::S3::Model::CreateBucketConfiguration createBucketConfig;
    Aws::String region("default");    // Empty string for default region (https://docs.ceph.com/en/quincy/radosgw/s3/bucketops/#response-entities)
    createBucketConfig.SetLocationConstraint(Aws::S3::Model::BucketLocationConstraintMapper::GetBucketLocationConstraintForName(region));
    std::cout << "My region: " << region << std::endl;
    request.SetCreateBucketConfiguration(createBucketConfig);

    std::cout << "BEFORE!" << std::endl;
    Aws::S3::Model::CreateBucketOutcome outcome = client.CreateBucket(request);
    std::cout << "AFTER! " << std::to_string(outcome.IsSuccess()) << std::endl;
    if (outcome.IsSuccess()) {
        std::cout << "SUCCESS!" << std::endl;
    } else {
        auto err = outcome.GetError();
        std::cerr << "===========ERROR===========" << std::endl;
        std::cerr << "Error: CreateBucket: " <<
                err.GetExceptionName() << ": " << err.GetMessage() << std::endl;
        std::cerr << err << std::endl;
        std::cerr << "===========================" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

### ListBucket

```cpp
void ListBucket() {
    Aws::Client::ClientConfiguration clientConfig;
    clientConfig.endpointOverride = "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:PORT";
    clientConfig.scheme = Aws::Http::Scheme::HTTP;
    clientConfig.verifySSL = false;

    Aws::Auth::AWSCredentials credentials;
    credentials.SetAWSAccessKeyId("____________________");
    credentials.SetAWSSecretKey("________________________________________");

    Aws::S3::S3Client client = Aws::S3::S3Client(credentials, clientConfig, Aws::Client::AWSAuthV4Signer::PayloadSigningPolicy::Never, false);
    auto outcome = client.ListBuckets();
    if (outcome.IsSuccess()) {
        for (auto&& b : outcome.GetResult().GetBuckets()) {
            std::cout << b.GetName().c_str() << std::endl;
        }
    } else {
        auto err = outcome.GetError();
        std::cerr << "Error: ListBucket: " <<
                err.GetExceptionName() << ": " << err.GetMessage() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

### DeleteBucket

```cpp
void DeleteBucket(std::string bucketName) {
    Aws::Client::ClientConfiguration clientConfig;
    clientConfig.endpointOverride = "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:PORT";
    clientConfig.scheme = Aws::Http::Scheme::HTTP;
    clientConfig.verifySSL = false;

    Aws::Auth::AWSCredentials credentials;
    credentials.SetAWSAccessKeyId("____________________");
    credentials.SetAWSSecretKey("________________________________________");

    Aws::S3::S3Client client = Aws::S3::S3Client(credentials, clientConfig, Aws::Client::AWSAuthV4Signer::PayloadSigningPolicy::Never, false);
    Aws::S3::Model::DeleteBucketRequest request;
    request.SetBucket(bucketName);
    Aws::S3::Model::DeleteBucketOutcome outcome = client.DeleteBucket(request);
    if (outcome.IsSuccess()) {
        std::cout << "SUCCESS!" << std::endl;
    } else {
        auto err = outcome.GetError();
        std::cerr << "===========ERROR===========" << std::endl;
        std::cerr << "Error: CreateBucket: " <<
                err.GetExceptionName() << ": " << err.GetMessage() << std::endl;
        std::cerr << err << std::endl;
        std::cerr << "===========================" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

### main function

```cpp
int main() {
    Aws::SDKOptions options;
    options.loggingOptions.logLevel = Aws::Utils::Logging::LogLevel::Debug;
    Aws::InitAPI(options);

    CreateBucket("bucket1");
    CreateBucket("bucket2");
    ListBucket();
    DeleteBucket("bucket1");
    ListBucket();

    Aws::ShutdownAPI(options);
}
```

### Running results (terminal)

```bash
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/AWSS3Test.dir/src/main.cc.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable AWSS3Test
[100%] Built target AWSS3Test
My region: default
BEFORE!
AFTER! 0
===========ERROR===========
Error: CreateBucket: Xml Parse Error: XML_ERROR_PARSING_TEXT
HTTP response code: -1
Resolved remote host IP address: 
Request ID: 
Exception name: Xml Parse Error
Error message: XML_ERROR_PARSING_TEXT
0 response headers:
===========================
My region: default
BEFORE!
AFTER! 0
===========ERROR===========
Error: CreateBucket: Xml Parse Error: XML_ERROR_PARSING_TEXT
HTTP response code: -1
Resolved remote host IP address: 
Request ID: 
Exception name: Xml Parse Error
Error message: XML_ERROR_PARSING_TEXT
0 response headers:
===========================
bucket1
bucket2
SUCCESS!
bucket2
```

## Conclusion

Please let me know how to solve this problem.

1. Should I contact with Ceph engineer? If so, how can I report this problem?
2. Is there any available options for not S3 but Ceph RGW ? (Like changing outcome style or etc.)
3. Do I misuse AWS SDK C++ S3? (I guess not. It is on [official documents](https://docs.ceph.com/en/quincy/radosgw/s3/).)